# Rails resque: Record not found when passing variable from controller to worker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, background-process, resque

I have  a very simple controller:

```
def create
  @poem = Poem.new(params[:poem])
  @poem.prose = @poem.content
   @poem.save
   Resque.enqueue(PoemWork, @poem.id)
 ....
```

and a very simple worker:

```
class PoemWork
 @queue = :poem_queue
 def self.perform(poem_id)
  @poem = Poem.find(poem_id)
  txt = @poem.content
  #do stuff here 
  @poem.save
 end
end
```

And I keep getting "Couldn't find Poem with id=53" or smth. like that...

I tried passing just string, just integer etc.. but it also ends with ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound

what can be wrong?

Comment: Is your background worker process connecting to the same database as the web server process?

Comment: Hmm... how do I check that? I have two apps that use resque and I use different redistogo dbs for them (defining them in resque.rb)... Also this is an error on localhost, have not tested it remotely yet

Comment: Provide the exact command you're using to run your workers. Are you running Rails locally in development mode?

Comment: bundle exec rake resque:work QUEUE='*'     yes in development mode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was that the worker starts before the object actually gets created.

Had to install the gem that restarts failed jobs.

[wrote the post about it](http://www.noletterword.com/blog/?p=606)