# Resque not recognising instance variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resque

I am using resque to send emails. The emails do not send if my mailer template contains any references to instance variables. The activation mailer worked correctly before I moved it to a background job using resque.

## users_controller.rb

```
def create
  @user = User.new(user_params)
  if @user.save
    Resque.enqueue(SendActivationEmail, @user.id)
    flash[:info] = "Please check your email to activate your account."
    redirect_to root_url
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

## send_activation_email.rb

```
class SendActivationEmail
  @queue = :email_queue
  def self.perform(user_id)
    user = User.find(user_id)
    UserMailer.account_activation(user).deliver_now
  end
end
```

## user_mailer.rb

```
class UserMailer < ApplicationMailer
  def account_activation(user)
    @new_user = user
    mail to: user.email, subject: "Account activation"
  end
end
```

## account_activation.text.erb

```
Hi,

Welcome. Click on the link below to activate your account:

<%= edit_account_activation_url(@new_user.activation_token, email: @new_user.email) %>
```

The error recorded in resque web is:
    No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"account_activations", :email=>"user5@domain.com", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]

The following will send when the link is removed...

## account_activation.text.erb

```
Hi,

Welcome. Click on the link below to activate your account:
```

The route is correct:

```
edit_account_activation GET    /account_activations/:id/edit(.:format)                             account_activations#edit
```

Comment: Are you using devise for user management (like the activation token)

Comment: The error is in line `<%= edit_account_activation_url(@new_user.activation_token, email: @new_user.email) %>`, post you `rake routes` output

Comment: The route is correct as before I implemented resque the activation email worked correctly.

Comment: Take the link out of the equation. The template does not recognise the instance variable at all.

Comment: @user1567212 as you say instance variable, i believe you are not storing it in the DB? but its auto generated.

Answer (score 0):

Just to make sure, change your `user_mailer.rb` slightly to use the `@new_user` instance variable to retrieve it's email in `account_activation` method.

```
class UserMailer < ApplicationMailer
  def account_activation(user)
    @new_user = user
    mail to: @new_user.email, subject: "Account activation"
  end
end
```

In your `config/environments/development.rb` file, Add:

```
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
```

This will notify you if there is any error in email delivery. You will be able to  check your develoment log.

Try these two things and let me know the update. I will update my answer after getting your feedback.

#### Update

When you said: `The activation mailer worked correctly before I moved it to a background job using resque.` what did you mean? Did you test it in production mode? or in development mode? In development mode, I think an actual email is not sent, but you can preview it (in Rails 4.1.x). When you get to a production environment, then you will need to set up an external server to send the actual email.

However, Add:

```
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
```

in your `config/environments/development.rb file` as per my suggestion above and then you will be able to see if there is any error in email delivery. Then, you can take the next step. Hope this helps.

Comment: Was working in production. Problem is ultimately the template cannot access the instance variable. I've asked another question to check my setup is correct first. I found this that implies there may be an issue with the workers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9335327/rails-resque-record-not-found-when-passing-variable-from-controller-to-worker

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the instance variables get converted from symbol-based keys to string-based. In my mail view I was getting values by symbol, so one can either get values by string, or call hash.symbolize_keys! to convert back to symbol keys.

The solution I found was from: https://github.com/zapnap/resque_mailer/issues/23